# Markdown files in Doxygen, two puzzles

Tags: markdown, doxygen

The environment is Doxygen 1.8.7 in Microsoft Windows 10.

I'm working on a Doxygen project that includes several markdown files, which all follow this pattern:

```
  1  Copyright (c) 2016-2017, XYZ CORP. All rights reserved.
  2
  3  @page xxx yyy
  4  @{
  5    Start of text
         .
         .
         .
       End of text
```

I've got two questions about this.

First, the file has no `@}` to balance the `@{` on line 4, yet Doxygen issues no warning. Is this just a bug or quirk in Doxygen, or is it valid for some reason I don't understand?

Second, this file produces (at least) two pages of output. One is titled `yyy` and contains the text from lines 5 and following, and that's fine. The other is titled `md_<d>_<dd>_<ddd>_xxx.html`,
where `<d>_<dd>_<ddd>...` are the names of the directories in the path from the repo's home directory to the file. This one contains nothing but the copyright notice, which is useless and looks stupid.

Is there a way to make this page go away?

Note, I haven't figured out how to reach the "copyright" page from the project's home page by clicking links. If there's no way to do that, then the page's existence is trivial. But I assume that because Doxygen generates the page, it provides *some* way to display it, which I just haven't found yet.

Comment: Sure you are using doxygen 1.8.7 (April 2014), the current version is 1.8.20...

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the comment the version 1.8.7 is a bit old (April 2014) and the current doxygen version is 1.8.20.
The solutions in this answer are based on doxygen 1.8.20 as for 1.8.7 they won't work in 1.8.7 (in 1.8.17 they should work)

In the the question there are 2 problems mentioned

- no warning in case of `@{` without closing `@}`. This is probably not correct but `@{` has no meaning in a `@page` anyway. <s>This should be investigated further and is probably worth a new issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose .</s>. I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8060, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8060).
- the removal of the "copyright"
  in a markdown file when the first non blank line isn't a page command (like `@page` \ `@mainpage` `text\n====`) doxygen will add a `@page` command with the name of the file as title. There are a number of possibilities to "overcome" this problem. Doxygen has a number of commands that make the contents more as less as comment and will thus not show up in the output. These are:

  - `<!-- ....->` i.e. the normal HTML comment signs (will also remove the that content from the other output formats)
  - `\cond [<label>]` ...`\endcond` in case ` evaluates to false or is not present the content of the block is not shown
  - `\if <label>` ...`\endif` in case ` evaluates to false the content of the block is not shown
  - `\noop ...` the one line text after the command is not shown.

  The problem here is that they don't remove the page reference (as the commands are  not seen non blank lines due to the order of processing), to accomplish this there is a solution:

  - move the content with the "comment" commands inside (at least somewhere after the first `@page` like command. So a solution could look like:

    ```
    @page xxx1 yyy1
    <!--
    Copyright (c) 2016-2017, XYZ CORP. All rights reserved.
    -->

    Start of text1
    ```

Looks like I already created some time ago a proposed pull request regarding the automatic handling of `<!--`: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6909

**Edit September 29 2020** The pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8060 has been integrated into the master version of doxygen.

Comment: Regarding the `@{` problem  I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8060, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8060).

Comment: `@page xxx yyy \n <!-- Copyright... ->` is probably the best solution. I'll have to find our legal department's original instructions to see if that's allowable. If not, getting a change of policy may be very hard. /// Regarding version: yes, I'm quite certain I'm using 1.8.7, and also that an update is not feasible. 1.8.7 is baked into our toolchain, and there's no perceived need to change that.

Comment: Well you might have a good reason to change it now (besides all the improvements done in the mean time in doxygen). It should not be hard to change the doxygen version it should work straight away. You also use windows 10 and this was even released after the doxygen version 1.8.10.

Comment: I assume you're using the plural "you" -- I don't remotely have the authority to do this on my own. There is virtually no chance that anyone else will think seriously about making a change unless some problem or requirement *forces* it. The workload is too great to let us do things we merely *should* do!